# lower semi continuous on Banach space implies locally bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $(X, \|\cdot\|)$  be a Banach space; and $f:X\to [0, \infty)$ is [lower- semi continuous](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-continuity) on $X.$

> **My Question is**: Can we expect $f$ is  bounded in some open subset of $X$ ?

[If answer is positive, I guess, may be [Baire category](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_category_theorem) theorem is useful; but I don't know how? ]

Comment: To clarify - you mean "is there an open set on which $f$ is bounded", right?

Comment: I suspect the question is whether a lsc function can be unbounded on every open subset of the domain.

Comment: @AC; yes, you are right;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there is such an open set.

Consider the sets $B_n = \{x \in X : f(x) \le n\}$. By lower-semicontinuity they are closed. If one of them has a non-empty interior, we are done. On the other hand $X = \bigcup_n B_n$, and by the Baire category theorem this is only possible if at least one $B_n$ has a non-empty interior.

Comment: thanks a lot; But I could not follow you; can  you explain bit more; (none of them have non empty interire, why we are done ? if one $B_{n}$ has non empty interior, why we will get boundedness on some open set ? ); thanks

Comment: @DivyangBhimani: The interior $U_n$ of $B_n$ is an open set. Because $U_n \subset B_n$, we have $f(x) \le n$ for all $x \in U_n$, so $f$ is bounded on $U_n$.

Comment: @JJ; thanks a lot;